# Is there a verb for online-ness and offline-ness?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

If I refer to the status of something as enabled and disabled, the verb is to enable and to disable.

Are there comparable single words for the status of something being online and offline? So far I've got "put online" and "take offline".

Comment: You might want to edit your text a bit. Clearly you seek a **verb**, but *"words for the status of something"* can only mean **adjectives**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"put online" and "take offline" are used for things, like servers or services.

"come online" and "go offline" are used to describe the action of a user using one of those services when he performs a login or logoff

So, sequentially, the service has to be put online, so that the users can come online inside that service. If the service is put offline, all users inside that service are forced to go offline.

Answer (score 8):

*Connected* and *disconnected*.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, *to come online* and *to go offline* are used in different online chat rooms/MMOs' ingame chats and other such systems.

Edit: Your own suggestion is another good variant, applicable if there is someone/something else that performs the operation. 
E.g. *My friend went offline right in the middle of discussion* vs. *We had to take the server offline to perform maintenance on it*.

Comment: OP specifically asked for "single words", implicitly rejecting in advance such combinations as *go/put/take/come on/offline*

Comment: Why not just "verb" the words and say "onlined" and "offlined"? Inspired by Calvin and Hobbes!

Comment: @jyc23 It may be just me, but I hate this practice. Both in English and in my native language (where it sounds simply awfull). Why reinvent the wheel, when there are already established phrases for it?

Answer (score 0):

In this day and age, if some resource is capable of being online at all, that is its 'normal' status.

The word *offline* does sometimes get used as a verb, as in ["I need to offline the server"](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=39675).

I don't know of any similar usage for the opposite process (I've never come across *"Online the server"*, for instance). Most people simply say *"reconnect"*, or *"put/get back online"*.

Comment: I thought the appropriate term for online-ness nowadays has become *live*, as in 'the website has gone live'.

Comment: @myqlarson: I think most websites would have been "online" for some time before "going live". It's just that they weren't publicly accessible and/or publicised before the "go live" date.

Comment: true. good point.

Comment: What's the opposite of going live?

Comment: @Matt: I don't think it's meaningful to talk of an 'opposite' to *going live*. It's like, for example, *reaching puberty* - either you do it, or you don't. Except that if you *don't* reach puberty then probably at least some medical people will talk about the situation. If your website doesn't go live, who would ever talk about it? And what would it even mean to call something a website in that case? My email address book isn't "live" in that sense, but I don't need a special word to describe what I've done to make it not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If the context is correct (i.e. it is established we are talking about something on the Internet) then you can say *available* and *unavailable*, although that's for state and not a verb, so you would end up saying *make available* and *make unavailable* which puts you in a similarly verbose position.

Answer (score 0):

"online" is not a verb; you cannot "online" something. You can go online, but then "go" is the verb.

It might be the case that you could think of "to go online" as a phrasal verb -- I suspect that in the future, "to go online" will become an accepted phrasal verb, but I doubt that "online" itself will every become a verb.

Answer (score 0):

From the users' perspective, a website is *accessible* when it is online, and *inaccessible* when it isn't.

EDIT: You're necessarily looking for  one-word. One option is *Activated* / *Deactivated*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two bits:

> *Log on* and *Log off*

When you *Log on*, you are online, when you *log off*, you are offline